# azure-maps-control StyleOptions interface is not style?: string its style?:vector

Tags: satellite, azure-maps, satellite-navigation

I am using azure-maps-control with npm, and I can not switch my map to satellite view, as in my npm package its shows in the `StyleOptions` interface style? Vector instead of style? string.

Can you please guide me how can pass 'satellite' value to vector?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the map to the `"satellite"` style you can do:

```
const map = new atlas.Map("<container id>", {
    style: "satellite",
    ....
});
```

Or after the map is constructed:

```
map.setStyle({ style: "satellite" });
```

Please note that the `"satellite"` and `"satellite_road_labels"` styles, as listed in our [supported map styles article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-maps/supported-map-styles), are only available to S1 accounts. This is because our [Get Map Imagery Tile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/maps/render/getmapimagerytile) is only available to S1 accounts.

If you are seeing 403 HTTP error responses printed to your browser's console or 403 responses to the tile requests, this is likely related to pricing tier. For more info on pricing tiers, please refer to our [choose the right pricing tier guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-maps/choose-pricing-tier).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am facing issue in the following code, this.maper.map.setStyle({style: "satellite"}); and in the ng module its shows me declare interface StyleOptions {
 language?: string;  // default: "NGT"
 style?: 'vector';  // default: 'vector'
 view?: 'Unified';  // default: 'Unified'
}; so I can not pass a string value to setStyle function